# Auto scrolling to active in-focus elements does not work on Android browsers

Tags: android, html, css, scroll

On iOS, touching the `input` field would trigger the soft-keyboard and auto scroll to the current in-focus element.

However, on Android browsers (Native or Chrome), touching the input field would trigger the soft-keyboard, but it scrolls to a wrong position so that the input is covered by the keyboard.

[DEMO here](http://jsbin.com/voyah/6)

I know that if I take out the `overflow:scroll` from the `parent` class it works well. But how to solve this if I need to keep the `overflow` ?

Comment: Do u want a scroll inside textbox??

Comment: @user3168736 no... I want the `parent` container to be 100% height so that I can have other elements positioning absolute to it

Comment: @MKYung Do you have the solution for this ? Can you share ?